# Bibliography separation with variable separator

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I need a "." behind the title and "," behind all other entries.

So far I tried to modify `output.nonnull` and `output.check` and extended them by an additional variable.

```
STRINGS { s t separator }
FUNCTION {output.nonnull*}
{ 
  'separator :=
  's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { separator * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION{output.nonnull}
{ ":: " output.nonnull* }

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check*}
{ 'separator :=
  't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    { separator output.nonnull* }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ "!!! " output.check* }
```

My parameterization in `@article` for example doesn't work and it is funny that I get the 3 `!!!` behind the title.

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date.front "year" output.check
  add.colon
  format.title "title" ". " output.check*
```

Any ideas? It seems like my function call doesn't take the parameters or that they go lost.

Does it have something to do with the way i access the variables comming from the stack ?

Comment: From which bibliography style did you start?

Comment: Why not just try to start from scratch with `latex makebst` and get exactly what you are looking for? See e.g. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/

Comment: its an own style i got from a friend, because of university regulations

Comment: @Dukeatcoding It is hard to see what goes on when we don't have the complete style to debug. So far I don't see any obvious bug.

Comment: In case I was not clear enough about it, please provide the complete `bst` file.